# Understanding BNF notation for an RTSP request

Tags: rtsp, rfc, bnf

According to RTSP documentation page 21 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2326, an RTSP response is:

```
   Request      =       Request-Line          ; Section 6.1
                *(      general-header        ; Section 5
                |       request-header        ; Section 6.2
                |       entity-header )       ; Section 8.1
                        CRLF
                        [ message-body ]      ; Section 4.3
```

The `*`, as far as I know and according to https://www.w3.org/Notation.html, means "1 or more of the thing after it". So I'm interpreting the thing above as

```
*(general-header|request-header|entity-header)CRLF
```

This would explain this example below, where the headers are of the type `general-header \r\n`, like this: `Cseq: 2\r\nContent-Base: rtsp://example.com/media.mp4\r\nContent-Type: application/sdp\r\nContent-Length: 360\r\n`:

```
S->C: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
      CSeq: 2
      Content-Base: rtsp://example.com/media.mp4
      Content-Type: application/sdp
      Content-Length: 460

      m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
      a=control:streamid=0
      a=range:npt=0-7.741000
      a=length:npt=7.741000
      a=rtpmap:96 MP4V-ES/5544
      a=mimetype:string;"video/MP4V-ES"
      a=AvgBitRate:integer;304018
      a=StreamName:string;"hinted video track"
      m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 97
      a=control:streamid=1
      a=range:npt=0-7.712000
      a=length:npt=7.712000
      a=rtpmap:97 mpeg4-generic/32000/2
      a=mimetype:string;"audio/mpeg4-generic"
      a=AvgBitRate:integer;65790
      a=StreamName:string;"hinted audio track"
```

The headers are in the form `general-header \r\n` (where `\r\n` is CRLF). But what about that extra white line (a `\r\n`) before the message body? This is not explained by the repetition.

I think I'm interpreting something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This interpretation is correct:

```
Request = Request-Line *(general-header|request-header|entity-header) CRLF [message-body]
```

Although the example given is a response, which has this similar grammar:

```
Response = Status-Line *(general-header|response-header|entity-header) CRLF [message-body]
```

In either case, the set of headers is separated from the `message-body` by a CRLF (`\r\n`), which is NOT repeated. In the example:

```
RTSP/1.0 200 OK                             # This is the Status-Line
CSeq: 2                                     # general-header (see Section 12)
Content-Base: rtsp://example.com/media.mp4  # entity-header (see Section 8.1, 12.11)
Content-Type: application/sdp               # entity-header (see Section 8.1, 12.16)
Content-Length: 460                         # entity-header (see Section 8.1, 12.14)
                                            # the CRLF marking the end of headers
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96                        # the message body follows
...
```

"The thing after the `*`" is the parenthesis block, without the CRLF. Each header ends with a CRLF because the grammar for message headers includes that. See Section 4.2, which refers to [Section 4.2 of RFC 2068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2068#section-4.2):

> `message-header = field-name ":" [ field-value ] CRLF`